# Using scanner in retrieving lines

Tags: java

am stuck with this question 
6) Suppose you enter 34.3, the ENTER key, 57.8, the ENTER key, 789, the ENTER key. Analyze the following code.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
int value = scanner.nextDouble();
int doubleValue = scanner.nextInt();
String line = scanner.nextLine();
```

i know the answer, the line will be equal to '\n' when the last statement is executed but why?

can anyone please explain it for me please?

Comment: does this code actually compile?

Comment: I agree with @Reimeus, you have a double that you have set equal to an int but have not cast to type int ?

Answer (score 1):

The Scanner reads as many tokens as necessary to get it's next output and then leaves all of the rest of the tokens there to be examined. `nextInt()` does not need the newline character so it leaves it in the token stream. When you call `nextLine()` it looks into the token stream, sees the newline character, and returns that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this statement by statement.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int value = scanner.nextDouble();
```

The system waits for you to type in the value.

```
34.3↲
```

The value is read as 34.3 but is truncated to 34 since it is stored as an integer. Now the next statement is executed.

```
int doubleValue = scanner.nextInt();
```

The system waits for you again to type in the value.

```
57.8↲
```

The value is read as 57 as you are using `scanner.nextInt()` and hence, the .8 is ignored. There is however a enter remaining in the buffer.

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
```

The system now waits again for the input, and you type in this. The first new line is the remnant from the previous input.

```
↲
789↲
```

The scanner first sees the newline character, so it assumes that the line is terminated. So the value is read as **\n**

Hope this helps.